# Why is React running slowly while lifting state up?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a game where one makes a maze and then exports that maze to a database for others to try. I'm making a very large grid (800 x 800) and turning the squares black `onMouseOver` to indicate the walls of the maze. For a while, it seemed to be working well, but somewhere along the line, it started lagging `onMouseOver`, kind of killing the game. I'm not sure if I can make the `div`s change color fast enough to make this functional.

It seemed to be working fine until I moved the id of the Square component to the state of the Maze component in preparation to send it to the back end.

Here's the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/reedmacdonald/mazeProject

```
class Maze extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super();
        this.state = {
            buttonClicked:'',
            buildShowing: 'inline',
            testShowing: 'none',
            testing: false,
            clicked: true,
            finishShowing:'inline',
            submitShowing:'none',
            maze:[],
            name:''

        }
    }


    changeToRed = () => {
        this.setState({
            submitShowing:'inline',
            finishShowing: 'none',
            buttonClicked:'red',
            testing: true})
    }



    nameThisMaze = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        var nameValue = document.getElementById("uniqueID").value
        this.setState({
            name: nameValue
        })
        alert(`name is now ${this.state.name}`)
    }

    handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const mazeResponse = await fetch('/maze', {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            body: JSON.stringify(this.state),
            headers:{
                "Content-type" : 'application/json'
            }
        })
        const parsedResponse = await mazeResponse.json();
        console.log(parsedResponse)
    }

    pushValueUp = (brick) => {
        this.state.maze.push(brick)
        this.setState({
            maze:this.state.maze
        })
    }



    render(){
        const arrayOne= new Array(6400).fill('hello')

        const theMaze = arrayOne.map((movie, i) => {
            return (
                <Square pushValueUp = {this.pushValueUp} scar={i} clicked =
                {this.state.clicked} key={i} name="brick" button=
                {this.state.buttonClicked} color={this.state.colorToChangeMaze}
            className= 'cell'/>
        )
        })
        return (
            <div onDoubleClick={this.changeToClicked}>
            <div onMouseOver={(this.state.testing) ?
            this.outOfBounds:undefined} className="outOfBounds"></div>
            <div onMouseOver={(this.state.testing) ?
            this.outOfBounds:undefined} className="outOfBoundsTwo"></div>
            <div onMouseOver={(this.state.testing) ?
            this.outOfBounds:undefined} className="outOfBoundsThree"></div>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <button type="button" onClick={this.changeButtons}
        className="finishMaze" style=
            {{'display':this.state.finishShowing}}>Finish Maze</button>
        <button type="submit" className="finishMaze"
        style=``{{'display':this.state.submitShowing}}>Submit Maze</button>

        <div className="grid">
            {theMaze}
            </div>
            </form>

            <button className="startEndButton" onClick={this.changeToRed} style={{'display':this.state.testShowing}}>Test Maze</button>
        <button className="startEndButton" onClick={this.changeToBlack} style={{'display':this.state.buildShowing}}>Build Maze</button>

        <form className="nameForm" onSubmit={this.nameThisMaze}>
            <input id = "uniqueID" name = "mazeName" className="giveName" type="text" placeholder=" Name of Your maze"></input>
            <button type="submit"> Give name</button>
        </form>
        </div>
    )}
}

class Square extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            scar: this.props.scar,
            color: 'white',
            colorToChange:null,
            changeColor: false,
            clicked:this.props.clicked
        };
    }


    darnThis = () =>{
        this.props.pushValueUp(this.props.scar)
    }
    switchColor =()=>{
        (this.state.colorToChange==='black' && this.props.button=== 'red')&& this.hitWall()
        this.darnThis()
        this.setState({
            changeColor:true,
            colorToChange:this.props.button})
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="boxes" onMouseOver = {this.switchColor} style={{'height':'5px','width':'5px','backgroundColor':this.state.changeColor ? this.state.colorToChange : this.state.color,'margin':'0'}}>
    </div>
    )
    }
}
```

I'm sorry I put so much code in there (I took out a good amount, in case you get confused as to where things went), I just don't know why the `onMouseOver` is lagging so much.

Comment: Could you create a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io)? It would be easier to fix something when we can see it happening.

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb https://codesandbox.io/s/github/reedmacdonald/mazeProject

On the NavBar click "MAZE" and then click "build maze and move your mouse over it to build the bricks. See how laggy it is?

Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few problems which I saw and fixed.

1. The 6400 sized array is not required to be created every time, since you only need to iterate 6400 times. Just create it once outside the components and use it via scope lookup.
2. `maze` is not used anywhere to render. So you can just keep it on the `Maze` instance, as `this.maze`. Calling `setState` will unnecessarily re-trigger the whole React lifecycle.
3. You call `switchColor` always in the `onMouseOver` handler. That's pretty expensive when coupled with a `setState` in the parent. Especially since the event is fired very often. So, I've moved the call to parent into `componentDidUpdate` and written some condition (`prevState.colorToChange !== this.state.colorToChange`) based on which parent is called. You should change this condition to suit your needs.

Codesandbox is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/9j8q089x5o). These are just some optimisations that I could think of, and the app seems to be responding well. Also remember, you should not [modify state directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly).

I experimented by using refs on each square. I didn't have time to make a full-fledged example, but the idea is there. [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/6w6mq79l3r).